# Opening an about: link in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Okay, so, I've been feeling like pulling my hair out on this one. I'm making my own homepage for school use, so I can easily and quickly do things.

I've hit a brick wall: You can't open "about:" links for whatever reason. Not using regular `href="about:`(target)`"`, not using `window.open("about:`(target)`","_self");`. Any other links work fine, but as soon as I change it to about:, nothing happens. At all. Might as well not have pressed it.

If anybody has any solutions, that's be greatly appreciated. They don't have to be cross-browser compatible, because I'm only using firefox. If the information is needed, I use Firefox 18 (I may update it next week).

Comment: ...many words @DaniloValente

Comment: I guess I got what I deserved for naming myself Doge, but if people could in future refrain from making Doge jokes and focusing on the actual question, that would be really good.

Comment: See the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052473/go-to-local-url-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use window.location.assign?

```
<a href="" onClick="window.location.assign('about:'); return false;">link</a>
```