# how i can get path of file from system using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, filesystems

I am working on an application using angular.js. I have a download button on click of that user will download file.I have another button for uploading same file on server.I don't want user to browse file and upload.I want to take file automatically from file system on click of upload button.Is it possible in angular.js or i need to do it by using another technology?

Every help or suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: You can use javascript to upload a file the user has selected. But browsers will generally prevent you from accessing local files from javascript on pages dowloaded from a server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052473/go-to-local-url-with-javascript