# Adding link to local file in Confluence

Tags: confluence

I would like to add a link to a local file in **confluence**. Obviously this link would only work if the file is locally on the users computer. I understand that.

If I add the address like this :

> file:///D:/dev/ngs-frontend/src/pages/myPage.html

The browser sends me to :

> about:blank

If I try to add it with quotes like so :

> "file:///D:/dev/ngs-frontend/src/pages/myPage.html"

..confluence crashes!

How is it possible in confluence?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned when adding the web link in Confluence specifying the file using the **file** protocol (file:///) you might face the issue that it doesn't work.

> Obviously this link would only work if the file is locally on the users computer.

This is not entirely true. If you open the developer tools you most likely will be getting the error "**Not allowed to load local resource**"

As measure of security the browser won't let you access files from a different origin, specially from the users computer (this would be a serious security risk). Only imagine if you could access the files in the Windows directory from the browser, you could break apart the operating system in no time (or steal user data).

This is explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052473/go-to-local-url-with-javascript)

If you put the file in the same server Confluence is running, then this should work just fine. However I believe you can save time just adding the page as an attachment and loading it (Confluence is pretty decent at [version controlling](https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf56/attachment-versions-658737034.html) in case you want to modify the html file).

Hope this helps!