# How do I embed a local video in a confluence page?

Tags: video, confluence

I want to embed a local video (.MOV) file in a confluence page.
I don't want to upload the video to the Confluence server.
The video is on a shared drive and should be accessible from within the company only.

The multimedia macro works only for videos that are uploaded to the confluence.
The Widget Connector works for YouTube or other external sites, but I couldn't make it work with my video, though I embedded it in a web page and tried to use the Widget Connector with my web page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to embed a local video (.MOV) file in a confluence page.

You want to access a local resource (the .MOV file) from a page that is hosted remotely (the Confluence server). This is **strictly forbidden** across all modern browsers for security matters (browsers run the page in sandbox mode, so you don't access the local filesystem). See more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40316239/5486521).

> The video is on a shared drive and should be accessible from within the company only

One way I'd do it is to upload the video to the Confluence server on a page with **restricted access**. You could create a group of users who can only access the resource, or just grant access manually to every user.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm currently facing the same problem there are two solutions that can solve this issue:

1. Setting up a web server that streams the videos from the shared file system. This can then be used by the built-in widget connector macro to embed the videos in Confluence.
2. There is a plugin for that in the marketplace called "Videos for Confluence", that according to its description is capable of streaming videos from a shared file system and embed them on a Confluence page.