# Replace url protocol in Chrome URL bar and reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, url, address-bar

I need to add a bookmarklet or something in **Chrome browser** to replace the protocol of a site to a local file.

Example URL:

```
https://st-test.com/folder/file.html
```

Becomes after clicking on the Javascript bookmarklet and it auto-reloads the page to:

```
file:///E:/st-test.com/folder/file.html
```

So it replaces "https://" with "file:///E:/" in the url and reload the page automatically.

I have found some suggestions here and there, using `history.pushState` or tampermonkey, but it seems they just can change the text of the url after the '/' but not the protocol.

Comment: I don't think this is feasible for security reasons, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14052517/1418049

Comment: @Maluen Thanks for the reply.  I already got the local files opening normally in Chrome, I just want the option for the bookmarklet to replace th protocol in the url, and then the page would load normally from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it might seem trivial, and if you tried this already then I probably didn't understand your problem.
I tried: 
`setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('https', 'file')
}, 2500)` 
And it worked fine. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried this but it didn't work: javascript:setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('https', 'file')}, 2500);  ---- am I adding it wrong?

Comment: <h1 onclick="javascript:setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('file', 'https')}, 2500)">Hi</h1> Try adding this, and click on the H1, it works for me. If it is still not working for you maybe you can add a code snippet please?

Comment: I think you are getting me wrong..  I want to add that to the bookmarks bar (as a bookmark), so when I open the https page and then click on that bookmarks, it replaces the "https://" with "file:///E:/"

Comment: Just to make sure I get you right this time - Do you want the bookmarked url to be saved with 'file' instead of 'https'?

Comment: Let us say I opened a site called "https://anysite.com", what I need is to click in a bookmark in the Chrome bookmarks bar, so it reloads the page with the following url: "file:///E:/anysite.com"