# Redirect from php file to a local HTML file

Tags: javascript, php

From a php file I want to redirect to a specific local html file.

I tried  the following:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
window.location.href='file://C:/DescMan/abc.html';</script>";
```

with no success. Don't have an error, only a white page with my localhost php address.

Also I tried:

```
header('Location: file://C:/DescMan/abc.html');

header('Content-Disposition: filename="abc.html"');readfile("C:/DescMan/abc.html");

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'; url='C:/DescMan/abc.html'/>";
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: By local, do you mean a html file that is not actually stored under your DocumentRoot folder?

Comment: For redirect, you need to URL not file path.

Comment: Always place an `exit` after a header redirect, otherwise the script continues.

Comment: Why not just print the file's content in php? `echo file_get_contents(...)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052473/go-to-local-url-with-javascript

Comment: Your 2nd attempt is promising but you can't have a `header('Location:...)` and a `readfile` you should just keep the `readfile` and nothing else

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes

Comment: @RP I tried...not working

Comment: @martinstoeckli I have exit after header...

Comment: @hindmost Because I want to redirect, no to print....

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Doesn't work

Comment: @apokryfos I tried, doesn't work

Comment: Why would you want to redirect to a page that is not stored on your server?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Why do you need this info?

Comment: To decide if it is worth pursueing a solution, or if the premise is so wrong I should just ignore it

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok. So when I press a button in `abc.html` is redirected in `z.php` page witch automatically download some info from database. After  downloading is finished I want to redirect to the main `abc.html` page.

Comment: And what is your web servers DocumentRoot set to?

Comment: In this case is in the same folder with `abc.html` but that's not mandatory

Comment: Then all you need is `header('Location: abc.html');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried that but when I do that is redirected and the page it's looking a bit different than what i expected and I don't know why.

Comment: _looking a bit different than what i expected_ What does it look like? What did you expect it to look like? Quite possibly we would need to see some code!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192359/discussion-between-bob-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: See the attach print screen on chat

Comment: I solved the problem using `header('Location: abc.html');` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to have the same result